# Integrate a WYSIWYG editor in Apache Isis

Tags: isis

Is there a workaround to integrate a WYSIWYG editor like Summernote in Apache Isis?

I found this New feature request in Jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1217 but I'm not sure it fits my needs.

I have a text field in which the user has to enter lists and images and I don't want them to write html code as they are not technical people.

I'm using Apache Isis 1.10.0-SNAPSHOT

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1265. We will implement it soon!